# Add a part of my form to the e-mail i receive using PHP

Tags: php, email

In my contact form i recently added a selector ( http://shopzuinig.nl/contact.html ) and styled it the way i wanted, but when i fill in the form and press send, the choice for a location is not included in the e-mail i receive. Can someone provide me with the PHP code to make this happen?

Here is my current PHP code:

```
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

$replyto='restaurant@dellitalia.nl';
$subject = 'Verzoek via de website';

if($post)
   {
   function ValidateEmail($email)
   {

 $regex = "/([a-z0-9_\.\-]+)". # name

 "@". # at

 "([a-z0-9\.\-]+){2,255}". # domain & possibly subdomains

 "\.". # period

 "([a-z]+){2,10}/i"; # domain extension 

 $eregi = preg_replace($regex, '', $email);

 return empty($eregi) ? true : false;
 }

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
$phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
$answer = trim($_POST['answer']);
$verificationanswer="6"; // plz change edit your human answer
$from=$email;
$to=$replyto;
$error = '';
$headers= "From: $name <" . $email . "> \n";
$headers.= "Reply-to:" . $email . "\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n".$headers;

// Checks Name Field

if(!$name || !$email || $email && !ValidateEmail($email) || $answer <>                 $verificationanswer || !$message || strlen($message) < 1)
{
$error .= 'De velden zijn niet correct ingevuld.<br />';
}

if(!$error)
    {
$messages.="Name: $name <br>";
$messages.="Email: $email <br>";
$messages.="Message: $message <br>";

$mail = mail($to,$subject,$messages,$headers);  

if($mail)
    {
    echo 'OK';
if($autorespond == "yes")
{
include("autoresponde.php");
}
    }

   }
   else
   {
   echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: in message only you are not sending any location information. how can u receive then.

Answer (score 0):

Location Missing in your message. Include location to get location details in your mail.

```
if(!$error)
    {
     $mydropdown=$_POST['mydropdown'];
     $mydropdown=mysql_real_escape_string($mydropdown);
    $messages.="Name: $name <br>";
    $messages.="Email: $email <br>";
    $messages.="Message: $message <br>";
    $messages.="Location: $mydropdown<br>"; // Missing. Include Location Here
    $mail = mail($to,$subject,$messages,$headers);  

    if($mail)
        {
            echo 'OK';
            if($autorespond == "yes")
            {
              include("autoresponde.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how do i label the piece of HTML as "location"?<p>
              <select class="custom-dropdown" name="restaurant">
    <option value="Restaurant/Kookstudio">Restaurant - Kookstudio Dell'Italia</option>
   <option value="Antipasti">Dell'Italia Antipasti</option>
   </select>
    </p>

Comment: That does add a location field to the e-mail i receive, but it's blank. So how can i make the choose appear the customer made?

Comment: what is your dropdown name of that restaurant dropdown. 
In http://shopzuinig.nl/contact.html, its name is 'mydropdown' and you commented as 'restaurant'.. what is the name. ?? tell me.

Comment: <select class="custom-dropdown" name="mydropdown">

Comment: @JSchel Now, see the edited answer. and,please let me know it's working or not.

Comment: In the first comment, you gave me wrong data <select class="custom-dropdown" name="restaurant">. Now, you gave actual data <select class="custom-dropdown" name="mydropdown">. So, be specific while giving proper data. It hampers all our efforts. @JSchel . In first comment, 'restaurant' name dropdown was not available, thats why it was coming empty in email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88371/discussion-between-j-schel-and-danish-enam).